# ejabberd and Erlang installation with lager_transform undefined

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, erlang-otp, ejabberd-module

I am new to Erlang, I have been trying to install Erlang and ejabberd on EC2 ubuntu machine, everything went well till I started compiling some external modules in `ejabberd`. It started throwing error `undefined parse transform 'lager_transform'`.

I tried everything which is as below:

1. Did rebar `get-deps`, `make clean`, `make deps`, `make install`. After this I am able to see that lager_transform.beam is made and present in `/lib/` folder.
2. Checked rebar.config file, it had lager deps on top, which is widely suggested, no help even after that.
3. Added `-compile[{parse_tranform},{lager_transform}]` on top of module, even then their is no luck.

I am really blocked on this, and not able to complete the installation. I have done this before on fedora with ejabberd 15.11 and otp 18.2, at that time it was using `p1_logger` instead of lager. But now when I am installing fresh with otp 18.2 and ejabberd 16.0 or 15.11, I am getting `lager_transform undefined error`.

Comment: How did you compile those extra modules?

Comment: Yes all extra modules were compiled, make takes care of that. I could see from the logs that modules complied and make install stated that lager_transform.bean is installed in //lib directory.

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure you compile ejabberd as described in documentation: http://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/installation/#installing-ejabberd-from-source-code

For example, you can compile it with:

```
./configure --enable-lager --enable-mysql
make
```

You need to run configure and make to set properly the build chain.

Comment: Thanks mickael, I will try with it. It was useful. Somehow missed it. But shouldn't rebar get-deps should take of it ? As it was installing everything ?

Comment: rebar get-deps is not enough. We have values with macros used by the code that do not get properly set if you bypass the standard ejabberd build chain.