# Cannot compile ejabberd when checked out from Git repository

Tags: git, erlang, ejabberd, rebar

I have built a ejabberd module in intelliJ using rebar to compile and I am getting the error "undefined parse transform 'lager_transform'"

rebar.config:

```
{erl_opts, [nowarn_deprecated_function,
{d, 'LAGER', true},
{d, 'NO_EXT_LIB'},
{i, ["c:/Program Files/ejabberd-15.11/bin"]},
{i, ["c:/Program Files/ejabberd-15.11/lib/ejabberd-15.11/include"]}]}.
```

I added these lines to the config file after checking responses on this site:

```
{deps, [{lager, ".", {git, "https://github.com/basho/lager", {tag, "3.0.2"}}},
{p1_utils, ".", {git, "https://github.com/processone/p1_utils", {tag, "1.0.3"}}},
```

I then proceed to try "rebar get-deps" but this fail with:

```
Pulling lager from {git,"https://github.com/basho/lager",{tag,"3.0.2"}}
ERROR: Rebar requires version {1,5} or higher of git to process {git,
"https://github.com/basho/lager",{tag,"3.0.2"}}
ERROR: 'get-deps' failed while processing C:/devxmpp/testMe: rebar_abort
```

So I proceed and downloaded git 2.7.x and still the same error.  It is not seeing the new version.

Regards,
Will

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ejabberd and Erlang installation with lager\_transform undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35144794/ejabberd-and-erlang-installation-with-lager-transform-undefined)

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate of this question: [ejabberd and Erlang installation with lager_transform undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35144794/ejabberd-and-erlang-installation-with-lager-transform-undefined)

You need to compile ejabberd as described in [ejabberd documentation](http://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/installation/#installing-ejabberd-from-source-code), with configure and make. rebar alone is not enough to set some initial define values for macro and will result in some part of the code being incorrectly defined / compiled.

Comment: Sorry about the duplicate, but I did not see that one.  That one was added a few hours before me.  Why when I use erlc like this it works              C:\Program Files\ejabberd-15.11\bin>erlc -v -DLAGER=true -DNO_EXT_LIB -I "c:/Program Files/ejabberd-15.11/lib/ejabberd-15.11/include" -o C:\devxmpp\prototype\mod_http_offline\src\ C:\devxmpp\prototype\mod_http_offline\src\mod_http_offline.erl

Comment: Why don't you use configure and makefile ? That's how it is intended to be used. Put your module along with other ejabberd source file and build ejabberd the documented way.

Comment: I will try this on my windows box and let you know.

Comment: I am not even sure you can build ejabberd on Windows, as there is native C code. You should use ProcessOne installer for Windows: https://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/downloads/. Then if you want to install contrib modules, either from ejabberd-contribs or from local code, you can use `ejabberdctl module_install` as shown here: https://blog.process-one.net/easy-installer-and-structure-for-ejabberd-contributed-modules/

Comment: I am having fit just trying to locate some of the requirement to setup the compilation tools for windows....I am not interested in developing on unix right now.  I will be using FreeBSD for server activities but not for development....I am trying none the less.

Comment: The toolchain is not done for Windows. You will have to write / test it on your own. That said, using the binary installer and rebuilding only the Erlang code is probably easier.